# Editing data in Listgrid's filter editor doesn't lead to fetchData

Tags: java, filter, smartgwt, listgrid

I have a `ListGrid` with filter editor set to visible.
Normally if I type data in filter editor it leads to fetching data from server and my `executeFetch(..)` method is being called.

But in some cases this method isn't called after editing filter's data. 
For example, if I type "**word**" it shows me some data in `ListGrid.`
Then I move cursor to the very first position, type "**one**" so all in all I have filter string "**one word**". And in this case fetching is not performed, and more over "old" data is shown no more. 
Maybe I need to disable some caching of resultSet/Criteria?

Here is my ListGrid declaration:

```
ListGrid grid = new ListGrid();
grid.setCanEdit(false);
grid.setShowFilterEditor(true);
grid.setDataSource(getSource());
grid.setDataPageSize(DATA_PAGE_SIZE);
grid.setFields(gridFields);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't you find it illogical to refetch on a more restrained criteria?
I will explain:

SmartGWT uses data caching to optimize client-server connections and reduce network traffic.
In your example, let's say you have the following in your database:

- one word
- two words
- one sentence

When you type `word`, the fetch returns:

- one word
- two words

these values are cached in your client.

When you add `one` to `word`, because this ss a more restraining search criteria, no need to server fetch, only client filter and the result is:

- one word

Comment: As I remember my solution was connected with `response.setTotalRows(..);`.
But in any case I appreciate your help much.